# How to compute the ratio of two large complex numbers

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, complex-numbers, largenumber

I am using R, and I have a fraction that is a complex number:

```
library(pracma);
sigma.jj = 1;
si = 2+3i;
N = 2*exp( 0.5*(- (sigma.jj^2)*(si^2)) );   # 23.39454+6.80796i
D = 1-pracma::erfz( (2^(-0.5))* ( si*sigma.jj )); # 2.225013-1.597002i
N/D;  # 5.489974+7.000163i
```

Notice, I am calling `erfz` ... the complex error function.  This is the source from the `pracma` library for that function:

```
# Complex error function
erfz    <- function(z)
{
    if (is.null(z)) return( NULL )
    else if (!is.numeric(z) && !is.complex(z))
        stop("Argument 'z' must be a numeric or complex scalar or vector.")

    a0 <- abs(z)
    c0 <- exp(-z * z)
    z1 <- ifelse (Re(z) < 0, -z, z) 

    i <- a0 <= 5.8
    work.i <- i
    cer <- rep(NA, length = length(z))
    if ( sum(work.i) > 0) {
        cs <- z1
        cr <- cs
        for (k in 1:120) {
            cr[work.i] <- cr[work.i] * z1[work.i] * z1[work.i]/(k + 0.5)
            cs[work.i] <- cs[work.i] + cr[work.i]
            work.i <- work.i & (abs(cr/cs) >= 1e-15)
        if (sum(work.i) == 0) break
        }
        cer[i] <- 2 * c0[i] * cs[i]/sqrt(pi)
    }
    work.i <- !i
    if( sum(work.i) > 0) {
        cl <- 1/z1
        cr <- cl
        for (k in 1:13) {
            cr[work.i] <- -cr[work.i] * (k - 0.5)/(z1[work.i] * z1[work.i])
            cl[work.i] <-  cl[work.i] + cr[work.i]
            work.i <- work.i & (abs(cr/cl) >= 1e-15)
        if (sum(work.i) == 0) break
        }
        cer[!i] <- 1 - c0[!i] * cl[!i]/sqrt(pi)
    }
    cer[ Re(z) < 0] <- -cer[ Re(z) < 0]
    return(cer)
}
```

---

You will notice that the N and D for each is getting large, but the fraction `N/D` is staying relatively manageable.

```
sigma.jj = 1;
si = 2+13i;
N = 2*exp( 0.5*(- (sigma.jj^2)*(si^2)) );   # 8.73323e+35-1.029433e+36i
D = 1-pracma::erfz( (2^(-0.5))* ( si*sigma.jj )); # -2.692745e+34-3.114988e+34i
N/D;  # 5.04326+32.39578i
```

At some point, R breaks:

```
sigma.jj = 1;
si = 2+33i;
N = 2*exp( 0.5*(- (sigma.jj^2)*(si^2)) );   # -8.046987e+235+2.13732e+234i
D = 1-pracma::erfz( (2^(-0.5))* ( si*sigma.jj )); # -3.31367e+232+9.716936e+233i
N/D;  # 5.01787+82.64292i
```

Now it breaks:

```
sigma.jj = 1;
si = 2+38i;
N = 2*exp( 0.5*(- (sigma.jj^2)*(si^2)) );   # Inf-Infi
D = 1-pracma::erfz( (2^(-0.5))* ( si*sigma.jj )); # NaN-Infi
N/D;  # NaN+NaNi
```

So I believe I could plug into some C++ libraries that could perform this calculation.  The numerator is likely easier that the denominator because of the complex error function.

I have included standalone C++ code within R before, using this link as a guide: [fast large matrix multiplication in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923787/)

Something like:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo, RcppEigen)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP armaMatMult(arma::mat A, arma::mat B){
    arma::mat C = A * B;

    return Rcpp::wrap(C);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP eigenMatTrans(Eigen::MatrixXd A){
    Eigen::MatrixXd C = A.transpose();

    return Rcpp::wrap(C);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP eigenMatMult(Eigen::MatrixXd A, Eigen::MatrixXd B){
    Eigen::MatrixXd C = A * B;

    return Rcpp::wrap(C);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP eigenMapMatMult(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> A, Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> B){
    Eigen::MatrixXd C = A * B;

    return Rcpp::wrap(C);
}
```

I am hoping for some help on the Numerator, which just seems like a large number, so a library that allows that.

For the Denominator, also handling of large numbers, but with access to the `erfz` function in a C++ library.

Then I can source it using Rcpp

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("multiply.cpp")
```

How to multiply (and take exponent) of large complex numbers in the numerator?
How to multiple and apply the complex error function in the denominator?

Maybe a function for each?

---

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/handling-large-numbers-in-cplusplus

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/complex.htm

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/erf

I am familiar with gmp https://gmplib.org/ but would prefer not having to implement that entire library.  Nor do I know if it will meet my needs.

Comment: Are you aware that [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) has R packages such as [Rmpfr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html) and [gmp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html)?  You could look at those and their reverse depends.

Comment: ```> si = mpfr(2+3i, precBits=80);
Error in mpfr.default(2 + (0+3i), precBits = 80) : 
  invalid 'x'. Must be numeric (logical, raw) or character``` This is library(Rmpfr) when I try and load a complex number.  `si = mpfr(2, precBits=80);` [no complexity] works fine.

Comment: Sorry, was worth a try.  Next up, maybe check Boost via package BH?